# Writing a simple function to count number of ones in a vector

Tags: verilog

As a task for learning how to write functions in Verilog, I am trying to write a function that just counts the number of ones in a given vector:

```
module m ();
 parameter n = 4;
function integer count_ones (input [n-1:0] a);
   
    for (integer i = 0 ; i<n ; i=i+1)
      begin
        if (a[i] ==1'b1)begin
          count_ones=count_ones+1;
        end
        
      end
    
    endfunction
initial begin 
reg [3:0] a = 4'b1;
integer result =  count_ones (a);
  
  $display("output is ", result);
end 
endmodule
```

The result is displayed as `x`. So what is the error in this code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare `count_ones` as type `integer`, which is a 4-state type, and its default value is `x`.  Also, `count_ones=count_ones+1;` keeps `count_ones` equal to `x`.

You should initialize `count_ones` inside the function.

```
function integer count_ones (input [n-1:0] a);
    count_ones = 0;
```

---

Keep in mind that there is a built-in `$countones` system function.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 20.9 *Bit vector system functions*.